# How come one doesn't need a Google Maps API Key to do this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

These 2 sites have some sample code on them. I copied and pasted the code into a php page in localhost, and they worked fine. However, the code doesn't seem to contain any API Keys. How come Google allows the code to use the Maps API without Keys? I'm obviously missing something here. What is it? Are there use cases where API Keys are not necessary? Where can I see the documentation regarding such uses cases?

[http://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/06/google-maps-geocoding-example-php.html](https://gist.github.com/lazarofl/3901081#file-geocoder_example-html)

https://gist.github.com/lazarofl/3901081#file-geocoder_example-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key to function correctly. However, we strongly encourage you to load the Maps API using an APIs Console key which allows you to monitor your application's Maps API usage

From: https://developers.google.com/maps/signup